# Extending promise pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, deferred, anti-patterns

Is it an anti pattern to extend promises with extra functions?
I have this example of a service that does API calls to Facebook:

```
FacebookService
    - importFeed(fanPage, sinceDate): Promise
    - importComments(fanPage, recursively, sinceDate): Promise
    - publishPost(fanPage): Promise
    - checkApiStatus(): Promise
```

---

This could be rewritten to

```
FacebookService
    - importFeed(): ExtendedPromise
    - importComments(recursively): ExtendedPromise
    - publishPost(): ExtendedPromise
    - checkApiStatus(): Promise
```

and used like that

```
var service = new FacebookService();
var fanPage = new FanPage(...);

service.importFeed()
       .from(fanPage)
       .since(new Date(...))
       .then(fn, fn);

service.importComments(true)
       .from(fanPage)
       .then(fn, fn);
```

What are the cons of such an implementation?

Comment: At which point would the call actually be executed in your pattern?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, I think jQuery does this kind of thing. E.g. the promise returned by `$.ajax` is extended to support XHR methods.

Comment: But maybe that's multiple inheritance, not extending. It returns on object that inherits from both Delayed and XHR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise is just an *interface*. Any object can implement the API and as such provide promise functionality.

The disadvantage is that your code is less flexible/composable if you rely on the added functionality. Other functions must know about and return such an "extended promise", they cannot just return *any* promise.